# CS0029: Cannot convert type List to Array in C#/Specflow

Tags: c#, automated-tests, specflow

I get the following error:

> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type
> Could you please help me how to fix it? I have tried a lot of things but I cannot work it out.. Thank you in advance.

Comment: change `AddUpdateData` to list or set it to array not list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like `AddUpdateData` is of type `CountryStateData[]`, but you're providing a `List<CountryStateData>`.

So provide an array instead

```
ManageCountryStatesData returnValue = services.BackendService.CountryManageCountryStates(services.ApiKey, services.SessionKey,
  new ManageCountryStatesOptions()
  {
    AddUpdateData = new CountryStateData[1] { myState }
  });
```